# How to locate custom font-face in CSS

Tags: css

I usually use firebug or chrome developer tools to inspect elements and they pretty much show everything.

What I can't find, is where the custom @font-face is located. Where the custom font is declared.

How can I find it?

Comment: Show us some code ? Or a link to the site ?

Comment: Any website that uses a custom font. How do you locate its font declaration? Of course without manually checking its CSS content.

Comment: You could, using firebug, look at the site code. Select 'HTML', and click 'Computed' that should give you all the data you need (and more)

Comment: It shows what the font name is and on what line that font is assigned to the selected element. It doesn't show where that custom font is declared.

Comment: If you click the [+] next to font-family, it shows you where in the css it's referenced. As to where it's declared that will depend on the type of custom font used . . .